# Need help with a Weierstrass M-test convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to use the Weierstrass M-test to show that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{x}}{3^{n}-5}$$ is convergent on $[0,a]$ for
$a \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $a>0$.  But I'm not sure how to find a
series of numbers $M_{n}$ such that
$\left|\frac{n^{x}}{3^{n}-5}\right| \leq M_{n}$ due to the numerator
containing $n^{x}$.

Comment: Use that $n^x \leq n^a$ on $[0,a]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may observe that, for any real number $x$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{n^{x+2}}{3^{n}-5}\right|=0
$$ giving that, there exists $C$ such that, for all $n\ge n_0$,
$$
\left|\frac{n^{x+2}}{3^{n}-5}\right|\le C \implies \left|\frac{n^{x}}{3^{n}-5}\right|\le\frac{C}{n^2}=M_n.
$$ then one may conclude since $\sum M_n$ is convergent.